# query issue on updating 56k fields

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MYSQL Update query -

```
UPDATE Aircraft
SET Type = replace(Type, 'A319 *', 'A319-*');
```

the current data is something like
A319 111
A319 131
A320 211
A320 214

I would like it to be adjusted to be
A319-111
A319-131
A320-211
A320-214

I KNOW this is so simple but I can't figure it out!

From Comments:

> Its all Airbus and Boeing Aircrafts, so from the A319 through to the A380 and from the B707 through to the B787

Comment: MariaDB has REGEXP_REPLACE(col, regexp, replace) otherwise you have to define replace for every type. Another option is to use user-defined functions, but you need to have an access to the server, where the db is running

Comment: Hi I have phpmyadmin access to the webserver this is held on

Comment: I dont mind creating scripts on for A319, one for A320 etc its mainly to ensure the "-" char appears after the A319, A320 etc

Comment: I think this can be done without user defined functions.

Comment: [pattern-matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) in mysql is done with `%` (none or more like your*) or `_` (single), however I don't think its needed at all for a . replace.

Comment: how many Aircraft types do you have, is it *just* A319, A320 or does it go up to A321,... A333 for instance?

Comment: Its all Airbus and Boeing Aircrafts, so from the A319 through to the A380 and from the B707 through to the B787

Comment: Perhaps you shold clarify this on your question, so you get better answers once people realise the data range that should be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Aircraft
SET Type = replace(Type, 'A319', 'A319-') WHERE Type LIKE 'A319%';
UPDATE Aircraft
SET Type = replace(Type, 'A320', 'A320-') WHERE Type LIKE 'A320%';
```

etc.

Comment: If for instance the numbers are A319, A320, A321... A333 this will become tedious pretty quickly.

Comment: This replacement would still leave a space after the A label.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround here is to update the `Type` column by building the string you want to use as a replacement.  This would be the first four characters, e.g. `'A319'`, followed by a dash, the followed by the sixth to last characters of the original column.

```
UPDATE Aircraft
SET Type = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Type, 1, 4),
                  '-',
                  SUBSTRING(Type, 6))
WHERE Type REGEXP 'A[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: If for instance the numbers are A319, A320, A321... A333 could you perhaps adjust the REGEX  (and `WHERE`) to accept numeric counts of A3xx ?

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the hint, I didn't check all the OP's data carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your other data is, but i think you search this?

```
UPDATE Aircraft
SET Type = REPLACE( type, ' ',  '-')
WHERE type LIKE 'A3%'
```

And you replace all the spaces.
Or do you have more examples of data?